# glossaries \glssymbol shows the latex command instead of the symbol

Tags: symbols, glossaries

I am trying to use the `glossaries` package to create a list of symbols. I've almost succeeded, but I run into a strange error. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-longragged}
\glossarystyle{longragged}
    \newglossary[nlg]{symbol}{sym}{smb}{List of symbols}
    \makeglossaries
   \newglossaryentry{Ffriction}{
        name={Friction force},
        description={\lipsum[1]},
        symbol={\ensuremath{F_\mathrm{friction}}},
        type=symbol
    }
\begin{document}
    \gls{Ffriction}

    \glssymbol{Ffriction}

    \printglossary[type=symbol,style=altlongragged4col]
\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex`, `makeglossaries` and `pdflatex` again, I get the following output:

[image]

The `\gls{Ffriction}` command prints the name of the entry as it should. But `\glssymbol{Ffriction}` prints “ensuremath –F˙“mathrm –friction˝˝, instead of the actual rendered symbol. The symbol looks just find in the glossary itself:

[image]

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Comment: Off-topic: Use `\setglossarystyle` -- `glossarystyle` is deprecated. As it stands, I can't reproduce your issue here

Comment: You can't?! I'll try if I get the same output with normal latex instead of pdflatex. Off-topic: what should I use instead of `glossarystyle`?

Comment: `\setglossarystyle`, as I wrote above. And no, I am not seeing the strange output.

Comment: Ah, I see how you meant it now, sorry. Latex produces the same output as pdflatex. Any idea what could be messed up about my tex installation?

Comment: I have no clue at the moment. Do you have the latest version of `glossaries`? It's version `2016/01/24 v4.21`

Comment: That might have been the problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled it but something went wrong, and I ended up reinstalling miktex altogether. It seems to work now!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved by updating the glossaries package(bundle)